# How to call fbq in angular 5 on click

Tags: angular

I need to add call `fbq('track', 'CustomerRegistration');` on click on a button on angular 5 app. How I am doing is as follows but its not working

```
declare const fbq: any;

public callFB(){
fbq('track', 'CustomerRegistration');
}
```

Call callFB() function on click , but its not working and giving me this error

```
ReferenceError: fbq is not defined
```

How can I call this function ?

Comment: I would try with `var` rather than `const`, and have you checked if this `fbq` function exist at the window object?

Comment: Be sure that Facebook Pixel script is included in the bundle, otherwise it should've worked.

Comment: Make sure you load the script from `index.html` or anywhere before angular bootstrapped. Otherwise the variable `fbq` won't be populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare fbq function in index.html file so that it will be available in components

and then use following code

```
declare const fbq: any;

public callFB(){
fbq('track', 'CustomerRegistration');
}
```